# min(which()) not retrieving the correct number under condition

Tags: r, min

I have a 4 x 600 datatable with 3 numeric columns with random integers ranging from 0 - 700. I have defined a variable as an integer with a value of 542. I am attempting to identify the minimum value that is greater than 542 in each of the numeric columns. However, the following works but is pulling the wrong value, any idea why? Or if I am doing something wrong?

```
#data.table called df with numeric columns being b,c,d

a <- as.integer(542)
min(which(df$b > a))
[1] 131
```

How is that possible? I know the correct value should be 543 for this column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from `which` is a position index and the the `min` applied on `which` returns the minimum position and not the position of minimum value.  Use the output from `which` to extract the values in 'b' and then wrap with `min`

```
min(df$b[which(df$b > a)])
```

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should know that `which.min` is equivalent to

```
which(x == min(x, na.rm = TRUE))
```

and it is definitely different from `min(which(x))`

Comment: Sorry it was one of the methods I had tried earlier with no avail, but thanks for the info. I updated the title as well to reflect that.